# WPF Update UI from override method not working

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to update a WPF UI from the ViewModel.

The View:

```
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:ConcreteObserver />
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Text="{Binding Key, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <Button
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            Content="Click"
            Command="{Binding TestDelegateCommand}" />
    </Grid>
```

The ViewModel:

```
ConcreteObserver : Observer<Mouse>, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private string _key;

        public DelegateCommand TestDelegateCommand { get; set; }

        public string Key
        {
            get { return _key; }
            set { _key = value;
                  OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Key)); 
                }
        }


        public ConcreteObserver ()
        {
            TestDelegateCommand = new DelegateCommand(UpdateGui);
        }

        private void UpdateGui()
        {
            Key = "Test refresh";
        }

        public override void Update(TestObject subject)
        {
            Key = "Test Update";

            if (subject is TestObject)
            {
                subject.MouseAction += OnMouse;
                subject.Start();

            }
        }

        private void OnMouse(object sender, RowMouseDataEventArgs e)
        {
            Key += "1";
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

I have an event that is triggered when I click the mouse and the event works fine.

The problem that the UI is not updated if the `Key` is changed within the update method and nothing is displayed on the GUI if the `Key` property changes.

I set a breakpoint and watched the change from the `Key` property and everything works fine but the GUI doesn't recognize the change.

I tested it with a button, the changes are shown when I click on the button

Can someone explain to me why.

thank you

Comment: Can you please tell me why you voted my question down? then I can update and improve the question

Comment: You need to at least add the following code to the Key property's setter:
_key = value;

Comment: I did it but it still doesn't work